# Configure platform page with platform specific options

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We've begun evaluating Xamarin for a up and coming project involving both iOS and Android, with the overriding intention to produce a single UI layer (and some share code, obviously) (I'm also new to C#)

## TL;DR

I've begun exploring Xamarin on iOS.  I started with the [Phoneword](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Phoneword/) example and it worked well enough.

The first issue I found was running the code on the iPhone X, which I was able to solve by using `MainPage.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);` in the platform `App` class

While testing this, I noticed some issues with the `ListView` not scrolling properly (the core issue was actually with the platform padding).

I then used `(MainPage as Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage).On<iOS>().EnableTranslucentNavigationBar();` to enable translucent navigation bars (as we're targeting iOS 11+) and now everything appears under the navigation bar.

This is easily fixed in xCode and after some research I've found that I need to be using [`UIKit.UIViewController.EdgesForExtendedLayout` Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIViewController.EdgesForExtendedLayout/), the immediate problem I'm facing is, the only "snippets" of code I can find are from the [View is displayed under status bar in iOS 7 and EdgesForExtendedLayout doesn't help](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8183/view-is-displayed-under-status-bar-in-ios-7-and-edgesforextendedlayout-doesnt-help) forum post.

## Issue at hand...

The example solution snippets posted seem to be making use of a platform (iOS) specific solution.  The problem is, I want to keep using the "cross-platform" code in the "platform" project and simply provide some custom configuration for the iOS platform which can apply these states.

I understand it could be possible to use a renderer, but this seems to counter-interactive, as I'd need one for both iOS and Android, where the platform page is doing just fine as it.

I understand that I could setup a DependencyService, but this seems annoying to have to include a specific "configuration" service just to solve this issue for iOS

I was hoping it might be possible to setup a iOS Page which would "override" some of the functionality of the platform page and would allow me to make use of things like `viewDidLoad` so I can apply the iOS specific configurations on a page by pages bases, so we could keep the platform page as it, but when running under iOS, it would provide me access to iOS life cycle of the actual view...

I've been trying to search the documentation and tutorials and haven't yet come across anything which would seem to do this or something similar (not to say there isn't one, but I'm just not finding it).

Comment: Your `TL;DR` is as long as the issue ;-) `Xamarin.Forms` does not use *multiple* VCs, storyboards, etc, the entire Forms' "application" is run within one programmically generated VC (Xamarin XAML or code-based Forms UI or not). Native customization of a Forms' page is done via renderers, dependency services, effects, etc... that all have a native implementation, Forms as you have seen, has built-in features to call these from non-native/NetStd portable code. That said, I've have clients that had specialized needs and in one case we mod'd the source and they maintain their own repo of Forms...

Comment: I assumed by request was “weird” it would be if it from some background. I’ve seen some examples extending from UIViewController and using things like viewDidLoad - is there any way to define a dependency back to the “platform” view so or am I just mis thinking this?

Comment: In a Forms' iOS app there is no external VC, in the iOS's App delegate's `FinishedLaunching` it inits the Forms code and loads the Forms' app (`Forms.Init(); LoadApplication(...`), that internally creates a VC that is added to the iOS Application window. So, if you modified the Forms' code, you could supply your own ViewController subclass, but there will only be one of this created, a Forms' ContentPage does not equal a VC... One VC contains all the Pages of your app, its single "VC" lifecycle, navigation, etc... Personally I do not see the benefit of this (in relationship to a Forms app).

Comment: That said, I do see how it would make sense in a native iOS implementation as I do this all the time with `Xamarin.iOS`, create a VC subclass that contains the various global features that I want every controller to have and thus be able to turn those features on/off each time I create a perform or create segue and "present" a VC to the user.

Comment: You could turn this upside down and use Xamarin.iOS and embed Xamarin.Forms ContentPage into VCs (via Form's embedding), but this is really flaky in actual real-world usage. If you are going to suffer the performance overhead of Forms' to start with and then have to deal with embedding just so you can use an Forms' `Entry` field instead of directly using a native `UITextField`, I would strongly just recommend skipping Forms and using Xamarin.iOS directly for the UI while keeping all the non-UI isolated in portable NetStd code if re-use is an actual  requirement of the project.

Comment:  tell it to my team lead